# javascript не работает set (сеттер) у объекта

Tags: javascript, объекты, set

```js
const array = {
  "bool_filled": "NOL",

  get he_filled() {
    return this.bool_filled;
  },

  set he_filled(x) {
    this.bool_filled = (x != "") ? true : false;
  }

};

console.log(array.he_filled = "223233sdff");
```

Подскажите пожалусто почему set (сеттер) не принимает значение, результат работы кода `223233sdff`, а должно выводится булево значение. Да я понимаю что можно сделать функцией и это будет работать но я хочу научится работать с get и set. За ранее огромное спасибо.

Comment: поставьте 2 равно для сравнения и возврата булева

Comment: Операция присваивания всегда возвращает именно то значение, которое было присвоено, то есть в вашем случае это строка. А то, что геттер будет возвращать булево значение, к присваиванию никакого отношения не имеет

Comment: Разделите ваш код 2 части. 1 - `array.he_filled = "223233sdff"`, 2 - `console.log(array.he_filled);` и увидите нужный результат

Comment: А почему вы присваиваете внутри `console.log`? Как сказал @SwaD, разделите на две части.

Comment: Всё заработала  после  console.log(array.he_filled == "223233sdff");
@RottenRat спасибо заработало

Comment: @SwaD Спасибо тоже заработало...

Answer (score -1):

Как я понял при "=" Присваивает значение
а "==" автоматически проверяет условие

```
console.log(array.he_filled == "223233sdff");
```

во втором ответе мне посоветовали разделить эти две строчки

```
array.he_filled = "223233sdff";
console.log(array.he_filled);
```

И это тоже работает потому что значение сперва переназначается а потом уже проверяется

Спасибо @RottenRat и @SwaD

Comment: Да вы правы, `=` операция присваивания, `==` операция сравнения, а именно равенства, но нужно учесть то, что при таком сравнении, сравниваются значения, а типы игнорируются, то есть выражение  `1 == "1"` будет `true`. Для того чтобы сравнить и значение и тип, существует такая операция `===`, в этом случае проверяется тип и значение, то есть `1 === "1"` будет `false`, так как хоть и значения верны, но типы у них разные, одно является числом, а второе строкой.